# django can't find template when trying to use forms

Tags: django, forms, templates

I am trying to follow the django documentation howto create a form using sjango form class. I am doing every step but when trying to access my form it says that is cannot find the template:

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: lform
```

heres is my forms.py:

```
class LoginForm(Form):
    
    uname=CharField(label='user name',max_length=20)
    passw=CharField(label='password', max_length=20)
```

the template lform.html:

```
<form action="ulogin" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and my view. I think the problem is in the render function:

```
def testform(request):

    if request.method=='POST':
        form=LoginForm(request.POST)
        
        if form_is_valid():
            return render('index')
        else:
            HttpResponseRedirect('index')

    else:
        form=LoginForm()
    
    return render(request,'lform',{'form':form})
```

and url.py:

```
path('lform',views.testform,name='lform')
```

the last line in the view function,

```
return render(request,'lform',{'form':form})
```

gives the error  any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

ok, the error was simply that the path to templates was missing somehow. I moved the template further up in the directory and now it displays the form. Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to render the template *lform*. Your template is *lform.html*.

You need to provide complete path to your template relative with your template path settings.

Comment: changing to lform.html gives the same error:
TemplateDoesNotExist at /lform

lform.html

Answer (score 0):

Correct your template name:

```
def testform(request):

if request.method=='POST':
    form=LoginForm(request.POST)
    
    if form_is_valid():
        return render('index')
    else:
        HttpResponseRedirect('index')

else:
    form=LoginForm()

return render(request,'lform.html',{'form':form})
```

In your settings.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ["templates"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: in my settings I have the following path: 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
everything else is the same as in your setting xample and I still get the same error after changing to lform.html

Comment: Where are your templates? Your templates should be in folder where your manage.py is.

Comment: they are further down: django/kammem/templates/kammem
but all other templates can be found, it is just this lform that cannot be found

Comment: what is **action = "ulogin"** in you template.

Comment: that is what happens when you press the submitt button, all according to this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/

Comment: try removing else statement which is " else:
        form=LoginForm()"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227274/discussion-between-shiv-and-jonas-fredriksson).